# How to use sample holder on Metallography specimen preparation machine Struers Tegrapol-21

Tags: materials, metals, grinding

In lab we have Struers Tegrapol-21 grinding and polishing machine. I use it for sample preparation. Usually I put 6 samples at once and prepare them with sample holder. However today I need to prepare 3 samples. I checked [brochure](http://www.struers.com/resources/elements/12/101288/TegraSystem%20brochure%20English.pdf) and it's not clear. [Manual](http://www.struers.com/resources/elements/12/282889/TegraPol-21%20-25%20-31%20-35%20TegraForce-3%20-5%20TegraDoser-1.pdf) wasn't helping either.

I'm trying to understand why do I use two different type of holders. Ease of loading is an issue however I'm looking to learn is there a difference in grinding/polishing performance. Why and when I should choose one over the other?

Here is photo of single holder (left), sample holder(right) and Tegrapol-21.

[image: Tegrapol-21]

### Question

1. Can I use sample holder for 3 samples?
2. Can I use single holder for 3 samples?
3. If both of them is possible which one is preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally have the tegrapol 11 and I use it with the tegraforce 1

Our units sample mover plate holds three specimens simultaneously (concept is the same though). Google tegrapol 11 and tegra force 1 for images if this is unclear.

Many times I run my sample mover plate both with only one and only two specimens at a time merely leaving the last hole(s) empty.

1. If I were working with this unit and I were concerned with using the sample mover plate sans all 6 holes being filled: I would distribute the three specimens (skip every other hole).
2. I would NOT use the single sample mover plate for three specimens.
3. As with 2. I personally would use the six-holed sample mover plate for three specimens.